# WSO2 V3.0 CORS Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I am trying to integrate my react js application with the gateway I am facing CORS issue as below

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://IP:port/userme. (Reason: header ‘access-control-allow-credentials’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).

everything is working from curb & postman request but not from browser.

Curb request (successful request)
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, PATCH, PUT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=37C2604B133C7B9D1345A9E13A878A36; Path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,Authorization
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 16:26:14 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is enabled by default for all APIs but you need to send following values in header earlier i was sending Access-Control-Allow-Headers and other values too which was causing issue.... 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'content-Type':'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+token,

Answer (score 0):

Try

1) enabling `access-control-allow-credentials` and

2) adding `access-control-allow-credentials` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list in the configuration.

Comment: I tried as suggested by you but no luck... I have enabled the CORS configuration for the api, checked the Access Control Allow Credentials and added the Access Control Allow Credentials in Access Control Allow Headers and save the changes... if i m directly sending the request (by pass the gateway) to back end api from application, it works well..

Comment: Enable wire logs and post your logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is sorted out... CORS is enabled by default for all APIs but you need to send following values in header earlier i was sending Access-Control-Allow-Headers and other values too which was causing issue....                                                                                                       'Accept': 'application/json',
'content-Type':'application/json', 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',